# Proper birational morphism from a Gorenstein normal scheme to a normal local domain, with trivial higher direct images, implies Cohen-Macaulay?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, schemes, birational-geometry, derived-functors, cohen-macaulay-rings

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic $0$. Let $R$ be a Noetherian local normal domain containing $k$. Also assume that $R$ is the homomorphic image of a Gorenstein ring of finite dimension, hence $R$ admits a Dualizing complex.
Let $Y$ be a Gorenstein normal scheme over Spec$(k)$ of finite Krull-dimension.

If there exists a proper birational map $f: Y \to \text{Spec}(R)$ such that $R^i f_* \mathcal O_Y=0, \forall i>0$, then is it true that $R$ is Cohen-Macaulay?
If this is not true in general, what if I also assume $Y$ is regular?

As $R$ is normal, $R$ is of course Cohen-Macaulay when $\dim R \leq 2$. So we only have to think about $\dim R \geq 3$.

Comment: I believe that this is a theorem of Elkik when $R$ is the localization of a finitely generated $k$-algebra.  Thus, it also holds if $R$ sits "between" such a localization and its completion (since you can check the Cohen-Macaulay property after passage to the localization).  So probably you can deduce your case from the Cohen structure theorem.

Comment: @JasonStarr: Thank you for your comment. Could you please give a reference for the case of when $R$ is essentially of finite type over $k$? Also, Is Spec$(R)$ necessary, or can we just do it for any normal scheme essentially of finite type over $k$?

Comment: I learned about this in Koll'ar's paper, "Singularities of pairs," in the Santa Cruz volume, but he references an earlier paper of Elkik.  I will try to track down the original article.

Comment: Elkik explains the proof in the discussion leading up to Definition 1 in the article, "Rationalit'e des singularit'es canoniques": https://eudml.org/doc/142810

Comment: I read the proof, and I think it probably directly applies to your situation, without using the completion.  I will try to write more soon.

Comment: Here's another quick reference when $Y$ is nonsingular / has rational singularities (at least in finite type situations or by Murayama's vanishing as below).  By Kovács' characterization of rational singularities, and the fact that $\mathcal{O}_X \to \mathcal{R} f_* \mathcal{O}_Y$ is an isomorphism and hence split, we see that $X$ has rational singularities too and hence is Cohen-Macaulay.  Indeed, you don't need $Y$ to be a resolution here (that's the point).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I started writing this last night, but didn't finish. In addition to [Jason Starr's answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/450348/33088), you can use my new vanishing theorems to remove the assumption that $R$ is essentially of finite type over a field. Note that the special case when $R$ is essentially of finite type over a field of characteristic zero also follows from Kempf's criterion for rational singularities [[Kempf 1973](https://doi.org/10.1007/BFb0070319), p. 50].

---

In short, if $Y$ is assumed to be regular, then $R$ will be Cohen–Macaulay. In fact, we have the following stronger result.

**Theorem.** *Let $R$ be a Noetherian ring and let $f\colon Y \to \operatorname{Spec}(R)$ be a proper birational morphism such that $Y$ is regular and $R^if_*\mathcal{O}_Y = 0$ for all $i > 0$. Suppose $R$ contains $\mathbf{Q}$. Then, every localization of $R$ is pseudo-rational, and in particular $R$ is Cohen–Macaulay.*

*Proof.* Since the conclusion can be checked locally, it suffices to consider the case when $(R,\mathfrak{m})$ is local. Set $\hat{Y} := Y \times_{\operatorname{Spec}(R)} \operatorname{Spec}(\hat{R})$, and consider the Cartesian diagram
$$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}
\hat{Y} @>>> Y\\
@V\hat{f}VV @VVfV\\
\operatorname{Spec}(\hat{R}) @>>> \operatorname{Spec}(R)
\end{CD}$$
By base change, $\hat{f}$ is proper, and by flat base change, $\hat{f}$ is birational [[EGAI$_\text{new}$](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/article?mr=3075000), Proposition 3.9.9] and $R^i\hat{f}_*\mathcal{O}_{\hat{Y}} = 0$ for all $i > 0$. Note that $\hat{R}$ is normal by [[Lipman 1969](http://www.numdam.org/item/?id=PMIHES_1969__36__195_0), Remark 16.2] and that the pseudo-rationality of $\hat{R}$ would imply that $R$ is pseudo-rational [[Murayama 2022](https://doi.org/10.1112/S0010437X21007715), Proposition 4.20]. Since $\hat{Y}$ is regular by [[EGAIV$_2$](http://www.numdam.org/item/PMIHES_1965__24__5_0/), Lemme 7.9.3.1], we may replace $R$ by $\hat{R}$ and $Y$ by $\hat{Y}$ to assume that $R$ is complete local.

We now prove the special case when $(R,\mathfrak{m})$ is complete local. First, by my version of Grauert-Riemenschneider vanishing [[Murayama](https://arxiv.org/abs/2101.10397), Theorem B(i)], we know that $R$ has rational singularities (see, e.g., [[Kollár 2013](https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9781139547895), Definition 2.76] for the definition). Since $R$ having rational singularities is equivalent to saying that $R$ is pseudo-rational in our setting [[Murayama](https://arxiv.org/abs/2101.10397), Remark 7.4], we are done.

We can also show that $R$ is Cohen–Macaulay directly. Since Cohen–Macaulayness can be checked locally, it suffices to consider the case when $(R,\mathfrak{m})$ is local. Since $R$ is normal, the map $R \overset{\sim}{\to} f_*\mathcal{O}_Y$ is an isomorphism [[EGAIII$_1$](http://www.numdam.org/item/?id=PMIHES_1961__11__5_0), Corollaire 4.3.12]. Combined with the assumption that $R^if_*\mathcal{O}_Y = 0$ for all $i > 0$, we have the quasi-isomorphism $R \overset{\sim}{\to} \mathbf{R}f_*\mathcal{O}_Y$.
Applying $\mathbf{R}\Gamma_{\mathfrak{m}}(-)$, we obtain
$$\mathbf{R}\Gamma_{\mathfrak{m}}(R) \overset{\sim}{\longrightarrow} \mathbf{R}\Gamma_{\mathfrak{m}}(\mathbf{R}f_*\mathcal{O}_Y) \cong \mathbf{R}\Gamma_{f^{-1}(\{\mathfrak{m}\})}(\mathcal{O}_Y).$$
Now taking $i$-th cohomology modules, we obtain the isomorphisms
$$H^i_{\mathfrak{m}}(R) \overset{\sim}{\longrightarrow} H^i_{\mathfrak{m}}(\mathbf{R}f_*\mathcal{O}_Y) \cong H^i_{f^{-1}(\{\mathfrak{m}\})}(\mathcal{O}_Y).$$
Since the local cohomology modules on the right vanish for all $i < \dim(R)$ by my version of Grauert–Riemenschneider vanishing (in its dual formulation) [[Murayama](https://arxiv.org/abs/2101.10397), Theorem B*(i)], we see that $R$ is Cohen–Macaulay. $\blacksquare$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will read it carefully, and will surely have many questions, but I quickly want to ask two things first: $Y$ is just a regular scheme with no other assumption? By $\widehat Y$, do you actually mean the fiber-product $Y \times_{Spec(R)} Spec(\widehat R)$?

Comment: I like your second argument... could you please spell out the Leray spectral sequence isomorphism ?

Comment: This is definitely better than the original version.

Comment: @SnakeEyes I edited my answer. For the regularity of $\hat{Y}$, see \[Stacks Project, [Tag 0BG6](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0BG6)\] for another reference.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit.** Thanks to user @Johan for pointing out the indexing mistake.  It is now corrected.

I read more of Elkik's article.  I am just expanding my comments into one answer. **Edit.** Assume that $R$ is essentially of finite type over $\text{Spec}\ k$.  By hypothesis, the scheme $X=\text{Spec}\ R$ has a dualizing complex $\omega^\bullet_R$ that has nonzero homology sheaf $\mathcal{H}^{\text{dim}\ R}(\omega^\bullet_R)$, and has vanishing homology sheaves $\mathcal{H}^i(\omega^\bullet_R)$ for $i>0$ and for $i<-\text{dim}\ R$.  The ring $R$ is Cohen-Macaulay if and only if the only integer $i$ with $\mathcal{H}^i(\omega^\bullet_R)$ nonzero is $i=-\text{dim}\ R$.  It is Gorenstein if, further, this homology sheaf is a projective $R$-module of rank $1$.

Also by hypothesis, the scheme $Y$ has a dualizing complex $\omega_Y^\bullet$ such that the homology sheaf $\mathcal{H}^i(\omega_Y^\bullet)$ is nonzero if and only if $i=-\text{dim}\ Y = -\text{dim}\ R$.  By relative duality, we have a natural quasi-isomorphism, $$\alpha:Rf_* \omega_Y^\bullet \cong R\text{Hom}_{\mathcal{O}_X}(Rf_*\mathcal{O}_Y,\omega_X^\bullet).$$  By hypothesis, the natural map $\mathcal{O}_X\to Rf_*\mathcal{O}_Y$ is a quasi-isomorphism.  Thus, $\alpha$ is equivalent to a quasi-isomorphism, $$Rf_*\omega^\bullet_Y \cong \omega_X^\bullet.$$

Since the only integer $i$ with a nonvanishing homology sheaf $\mathcal{H}^i(Rf_*\omega^\bullet_Y)$ is $i=-\text{dim}\ Y$, the complex $Rf_*\omega^\bullet_Y$ has nonvanishing homology sheaves $R^if_*\omega^\bullet_Y$ only for $ -\text{dim}\ Y \leq i \leq 0$.

**Edit.** Since $R$ is essentially of finite type and $Y$ is regular, by Grauert-Riemenschneider Vanishing the derived direct image $R^if_*\omega^\bullet_Y$ is nonzero only for $i=-\text{dim}\ Y = -\text{dim}\ R$, in which degree it equals $f_*\mathcal{H}^{-\text{dim}\ Y}(\omega^\bullet_Y)$.

Thus the complex $\omega_X^\bullet$ has nonvanishing homology sheaves only for $i =- \text{dim}\ R = \text{dim}\ Y$. Therefore $R$ is Cohen-Macaulay.

Comment: Sorry, Jason, but there is something wrong with the numbering. Usually, people normalize the dualizing complex of R such that it has nonzero cohomology in degrees $[-\dim R, 0]$. When I use that normalization I have to use Grauert-Riemenschneider vanishing as in the article of Elkik. Cheers!

Comment: You are right: I misread the indexing convention.  I will correct it now.

Comment: I know that $\omega_Y^{\bullet}$ is only supported at $\dim Y$, but could you please explain why $\mathcal H^i(Rf_* \omega_Y^{\bullet })=0$ for $i\neq -\dim Y$? If we can just say this, we would be done at this point, no? Because $X$ is Cohen-Macaulay if and only if $\omega_X^{\bullet}$ is supported in a single degree ...

Comment: As pointed out by user @Johan (and explained in the article by Elkik), this follows from Grauert-Riemenschneider Vanishing.

Comment: @JasonStarr: Thank you for your edits ... I do not have a reference in front of me right now, but for Grauert-Riemenschneider, don't you need both the schemes to be actually a variety over a characteristic $0$ field?

Comment: @JasonStarr I assume $Y$ is nonsingular (or more generally has rational singularities) so you get the vanishing (ie, see Takumi's answer below).

Comment: Yes, Grauert-Riemenschneider (at least the original version) does require the target to be of finite type over a field.  Of course using limit theorems, it suffices for the target to be essentially of finite type over a field.  That is why I had to add the hypothesis that $R$ is essentially of finite type.